# How to display a mailbox as browsable website?

Tags: website, hosting, mailing-lists

We have a company-wide mailing list that aggregates all its messages in one IMAP/POP3 mailbox. Now we would like to make the contents of this mailbox browsable as an internal website.
The goal is to be able to refer back to some older discussion without resending all the messages it consisted of.

Also, we are kind of limited by our hosting service, which only allows Perl, Python and PHP, but no compiled programs or CPAN modules. Not even the PHP IMAP module.

I am thinking of something like the system used at [cocoabuilder.com](http://www.cocoabuilder.com).

Answer (score 4):

If you have a shell account, you can install CPAN modules without needing any special permissions and without affecting other users. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251705/how-can-i-use-a-new-perl-module-without-install-permissions.

If you don't have a shell account, you can install pure-Perl modules by uploading the .pm files into a subdirectory of your home directory.